# Are React.js props only for passing data between components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that owns many child components. In `render()`, I have to loop through each of the items to build the children. During this loop, I check each item to see if it is "the special one". If it is, I store it in a variable.

I do this because `componentDidMount` defines a frequently referenced event handler that needs a reference to the special item (and that doesn't want to loop through all of the items repeatedly).

Is it idiomatic in React to store this reference in `this.props.specialItem` or `this.specialItem`?

Here is an example of the situation in psuedocode:

```
var ItemList = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 27) {
        this.setState({ currentItem: this.specialItem });
        return;
      }
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    var items = _.map(this.state.data, function(item) {
      if (!this.specialItem && this.isSpecial(item)) {
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        this.specialItem = item;
        // or should this be this.props.specialItem ?
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      }
      // ...
    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your pseudo code, we know a few things:

- `this.state.data` is an array of items
- `this.isSpecial(item)` tells us if an item is the special one
- when <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed, we want to set `state.currentItem` to the special item

With this, we can remove this special logic from the render function, and only have it in our keypress handler.

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 27) {
            var special = this.state.data.find(this.isSpecial);
            this.setState({currentItem: special});
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

This does rely on [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill), which is lazy (so more efficient), and we're only doing this check when the user presses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key... which is probably much less often than your render function being called.

If the user is going to be hitting this key a lot, you might have slightly better performance by storing it in `this.specialItem` in `componentWillRecieveProps`.

---

> Is it idiomatic in React to store this reference in this.props.specialItem or this.specialItem?

You should never set a prop with `this.props.anything = something`.

And as always, don't forget to remove your event handlers in `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: I agree that putting the lookup for the special item would ideally belong in the event handler, but in this case, `render` already loops through all of the items anyway, `this.isSpecial()` is an extremely inexpensive lookup, and I expect the user to hit the event handler more frequently than the psuedocode might suggest :) In any case, this is all good advice, and you answered my question. Thank you very much!